# Send/Publish message from with Service Bus to RabbitMQ?

Tags: python, azure, rabbitmq, azureservicebus, rabbitmq-exchange

I knwo that's possible to send messages from RabbitMQ to Azure Service Bus, documentation in Microsoft Azure.

From my use case, I look to do the inverse : send message from Azure Service Bus to RabbitMQ and be consume.
Is it possible? Thank you.

Comment: `Shovel plugin`, can handle that as well, it can treat ASB as AMQP source, and the RabbitMQ as destination, I think so.

Comment: Have you explored this: https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/bridge/

Comment: Thanks @AnansSowithiran for your feedback. I use Shovel plugin to create bridge between Azure Service Bus and Rabbitmq.